# VER DIRECTORIOS EN TURBO C++ 3.2

Tags: c++

tengo un código que crea directorios  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
 pero el problema es que no encuentro el programa para que lo lea,alguna idea de como seria?

Comment: Hola Andrea, bienvenida. Hace mil años que no veo esa hermosa pantalla azul. Si queres compilar usa Alt-F9 tal como dice ahí. Y para ejecutar algo por linea de comandos solo escribes ./<nombre del archivo> por ejemplo ./miprograma

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la librería dirent.h (POSIX), su implementación sería algo así:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>

DIR* dirp = opendir("."); // Aquí sería el directorio a mostrar
struct dirent * dp;
while ((dp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
    printf("%s", dp->d_name);
}
closedir(dirp);
```

Puedes ver otros métodos o técnicas en http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/list-the-files-in-a-directory-in-c.html

Comment: Muchisimaaaaaas gracias llevo 2 semanas tratando de encontrar el programa se lo agradezco muchisimooo